# Could not call incremental task error in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-maps-api-2

So I have bees stuck on this all day on android studio.

I have tried to follow this tutorial to add support for google maps API for my application

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_the_android_sdk

but when I try to build the application this error appears

Gradle: Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.

> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':dexDebug'

here is my build.gradel

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'


    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

When I remove remove this line for testing the said error doesn't appear.

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

Does anyone know what the error code be?

Comment: What do you get if you compile from the command line with the --info option?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Play Services installed? In Android Studio, go to the SDK Manager. Under Extras, make sure you have the latest revision of Google Play services. After you install, you may have to restart Android Studio.

To double-check that 4.0.30 was downloaded, you can check that the Android Studio's local Maven repository contains the folder. The path is something like:

/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/4.0.30